# How to reduce the number of HTTP requests in an AJAX-heavy web application?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I am building a MVC javascript application which has most of the logic on the frontend, leaving the backend with the API only, with the modals on the frontend.

However, I think there are some design and performance problems. Considering the following case with a RESTful backend:

1. User issues `GET /` for the first HTML page including the Javascript application.
2. The page loads up the Javascript application, issuing `GET /api/articles?limit=30` to pull the first 30 articles in JSON, which will be rendered to the browser by Javascript application.
3. For each of the article, there are comments with it. So each article will individually make an ajax request  `GET /api/article/<article_id>/comments` to fetch the associated comments also to be rendered also.

As such, there are already more than 30 requests for a single page visit, which induces a lot of HTTP overheads and it does not seem correct.

Can somebody recommend the correct way to do it? Am I designing something wrong? Is RESTful backend useful in this case? What are some other suggestions of communication architecture between a JavaScript-heavy frontend and a backend API?

Comment: Why request comments for articles the user isn't viewing? If you're loading up a collection of articles, wait until the user clicks through to an article then load up the comments for said article. You could also nest the comments in your index end point of the articles for your REST api depending on how ugly of a query it would generate.

Comment: You can also bootstrap your articles on the initial page load so you're not having to request them as soon as the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I would not fetch for all comments for each article, but would like to display the last several comments of them. When user click on "display previous comments" the rest will be shown.

Nest the comments in the index end point? Should I put the query in the frontend javascript or should the logic be embedded on the backend? Would you give me some examples of the "ugly query" please?

Comment: Adding an example as an answer so its easier to read.

Comment: @Mark, for your second comment, is bootstrapping usually the case for initial page load a good practice? It seems to defeat the purpose of the Javascript application, which is responsible to rendering the DOM elements.

Comment: I agree with Mark. More than the payload it is the headers and the number of requests that take more bandwidth and time. You can create a new endpoint which would return all the articles (in this case 30) and top few comments for each of the article in a single call. That way you have to make a single request.

Comment: @hllau bootstrapping doesn't change the functionality of your client side application. The only difference bootstrapping would do is on the initial page load where the user is requesting all your javascript, css, and html, you can include a <script> block on the page that contains the JSON that would normally be returned by /api/articles. The benefit here would be that for the initial load of your application you wouldn't have to fetch articles because they already exist. Using Javascript you would parse the JSON that was bootstrapped instead of fetching it via ajax.

Comment: Great idea, @Mark on including the JSON script on initial load. Thank you for your information. Do you know where I can learn more about these design practices of AJAX application please?

Comment: A good community driven book that is frequently updated called Backbone on Rails https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails Although you may not be using either backbone.js or Ruby on Rails, the book has some good best practices on bootstrapping, performance that could be applied to any project regardless of frameworks.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark. Will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what framework you are working with for your backend but the backend would query all your articles and also include (for example) the latest 3 comments per article.

Your JSON returned by /api/articles?limit=30 could look like this:

```
[
    {
        title: "Article Title",
        comments : [
            {
               comment: "Hi",
               author: "Me"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Seems a lot more work is involved. Like, I have to store the location of the comment so that I can retrieve the rest of the comments correctly.

Comment: @hllau not sure I follow, do you not have a one to many relationship between articles and comments?

Comment: yes I do. Backend is MySQL, using Python Flask as the API. So, for the JSON, there will be an extra field called `previous_comment_id`? What do you think?

Comment: you would want the actual comment not just the ID. In my example, comments would contain an array of comments objects.